# why both the programs are working same? it is about using bitwise operator to find odd or even number (C)

Tags: c

I Know How This Program works this is the 1st one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n&1==1)
    {
        printf("%d is an odd number\n", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is an even number\n", n);
    }
}
```

Program below to 1st program is the 2nd program, in that program, it has been written n&1 instead of n&1==1, this works same as 1st program but the problem is that in this program I have written n&1 instead of n&1==1 still the programs works fine (ho2) and it has same outputs compared to 1st program i was learning that how to use bitwise operator to find whether a given number is odd or even from youtube and i saw this program(2nd program below to 1st program) on youtube.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n&1)
    {
        printf("%d is an odd number\n", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is an even number\n", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first case is suffering from operator precedence, and should be `if((n & 1) == 1)`. The code given is acting like `if(n & (1 == 1))`. But, since `1 == 1` is `1` they act the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right about the precedence, but in this case `n&1==1` is equivalent to `n&1`, which behaves the same as `(n&1)==1`, so I don't think there should be a visible difference between any of these.  They will all be `1` if the low-order bit of `n` is `1`, and `0` otherwise.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes I added that as you were typing.

Comment: Only for this corner case: in other cases the parentheses matter.

Comment: @ThUnDeRØXD If you want them to be different, you need to use a different second operand, or a different operand order.  For example, `1&n==1` will behave differently from `1&n` when `n` is `5`.  The former is `0`, and the latter is `1`.

Comment: If the case had been `if (n&2 == 2)`, then it should not be equivalent to `if (n&2)` (but it  should have been equivalent to `if ((n&2) == 2)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, any non-zero number is considered to be true.

To understand, let's take two small numbers, say 5 and 6. The binary representations are `101` and `110`. `1` in three bits is `001`.

Now, when we check the second program's condition for 5, we have:

```
   if (101 & 001)
=> if (001)
=> if (true) // Since 001 = 1 != 0
```

Similarly, for 6:

```
   if (110 & 001)
=> if (000)
=> if (false) // Since 000 = 0
```